# Jquery selecting child inside prev not working

Tags: jquery

The code:

```
  <article>
    <a href="#"><h4>h4 inside anchor</h4></a>
    <p>This is a sibling paragraph of that anchor which had h4 in it</p>
  </article>
  <script>
    $('article p').click(function(){
      $(this).prev('a h4').css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
  </script>
```

When I click on the paragraph, I expect the h4 to get a background color of yellow, but it's not working.

Also the JQuery documentation on "prev" is not quite clear about selectors with descendants inside prev (so the first implication is that it's not different from the common expected behavior of selectors):

> If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that **selector**.

so what is wrong?

Comment: *"only if it matches that selector"* - the previous sibling is `<a>` - it does not match the selector `a h4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you're using a child selector in the `prev()` call. Internally jQuery uses logic similar to `is()` to determine if the sibling elements match this selector, therefore it will test if the `a` *is* a `h4`, which can never be the case.

To fix this use a combination of `prev()` and `find()`:

```js
$('article p').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('a').find('h4').addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight { background-color: #FF0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <a href="#">
    <h4>h4 inside anchor</h4>
  </a>
  <p>This is a sibling paragraph of that anchor which had h4 in it</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the 'a' in the prev as the prev will have already selected the 'a' and you just need to specify that you now want the 'h4', updated:

```
$(this).prev().find('h4').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article>
    <a href="#"><h4>h4 inside anchor</h4></a>
    <p style="cursor:pointer">This is a sibling paragraph of that anchor which had h4 in it</p>
  </article>
  
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click','article p',function(){
      $(this).prev('a').find('h4').css("background-color", "yellow");
     });
    });  
  </script>
```